# Remove trailing whitespace and newlines after edit submission

Tags: feature-request, edits, whitespace

After an edit please can all trailing white space and newlines be removed? By that I mean at the end of the question.

I know it doesn't affect the output but it doesn't need to be there, and can create scroll bars in the edit window.

I find that after moving text around in an edit, and deleting lines, I can be left with 5 or more new lines at the end of my edit.

Comment: And newlines also :)

Comment: It's not displayed, but it's saved.

Comment: @Won't as you just saw :P

Comment: If this option is removed, how else are we going to make void edits? Void edits are standard practice if you want to unlock your vote.